# How to create a cumulative line graph from a data frame containing a list of date time values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a large data frame with a 'date_joined' column, indicating the date that members joined a certain forum. I wish to plot a line graph that cumulatively counts the number of members joining each day, with date on the x axis and the y axis indicating the count value for each date (the number of people who joined on that date). What is the best way to do this?

I would also like to lay this line graph over a bar chart or histogram that counts the number of members who joined on each day - though my data set covers a period of five years so it would be good to group this based on months.

My data looks something like this:

| user_name | thread_name | post_text | date_joined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BoxCutter | Expierence with my coworker | .... | 2018-05-02 |
| Mainlander | Expierence with my coworker | ..... | 2022-03-25 |

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you share a sample of the data?

Comment: In general, groupby the data column and apply sum will give you the number per day, then np.cumsum on all the day sums will give you the data for the line you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little unclear what you meant with on top, so here are tow solutions:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'user_name': ['BoxCutter', 'Mainlander', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Eve'],
        'thread_name': ['Experience with my coworker', 'Experience with my boss', 'Experience with my manager', 'Experience with my team', 'Experience with my job'],
        'post_text': ['...', '...', '...', '...', '...'],
        'date_joined': ['2018-05-02', '2022-03-25', '2019-12-10', '2020-06-15', '2021-09-01']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date_joined'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_joined'])

daily_count = df.groupby('date_joined').count()

cumulative_count = daily_count.cumsum()

plt.plot(cumulative_count.index, cumulative_count['user_name'])
plt.xlabel('Date Joined')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Count of Members')
plt.title('Cumulative Count of Members Joined Over Time')
plt.show()

df['year_month'] = df['date_joined'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
monthly_count = df.groupby('year_month')['user_name'].count()
plt.bar(monthly_count.index, monthly_count)
plt.xlabel('Year-Month Joined')
plt.ylabel('Count of Members Joined')
plt.title('Count of Members Joined Each Month')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

will produce

[image]
[image]

and

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'user_name': ['BoxCutter', 'Mainlander', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Eve'],
        'thread_name': ['Experience with my coworker', 'Experience with my boss', 'Experience with my manager', 'Experience with my team', 'Experience with my job'],
        'post_text': ['...', '...', '...', '...', '...'],
        'date_joined': ['2018-05-02', '2022-03-25', '2019-12-10', '2020-06-15', '2021-09-01']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date_joined'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_joined'] )
df['join_month'] = df['date_joined'].dt.to_period('M')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax1.hist(df['date_joined'], bins=60, alpha=0.5, color='blue', edgecolor='black')
ax1.set_xlabel('Date joined')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count')
ax1.set_title('Number of members joined per month')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

df_line = df.groupby('date_joined').size().cumsum().reset_index(name='cumulative_count')
ax2.plot(df_line['date_joined'], df_line['cumulative_count'], color='red', linewidth=2)
ax2.set_ylabel('Cumulative count')

plt.show()
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I was after! thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. Upvote if you are reaaaalllly happy.